# Let's have a [baby]!

Tags: discussion, tags

While posting [this question about breastfeeding](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12015/3379), I noticed that there is no [baby](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby). There are a number of good questions where it would apply:

- [Is there a recent life cycle analysis for cloth diaper and for disposable diaper?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/7086/3379)
- [Sustainable diapers?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5951/3379)
- [Reusable vs. disposable diapers: which is better?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/907/3379)
- [Tissues or cloth to clean a baby - what's more sustainable?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2376/3379)

**Any objections to creating this tag? is there a better alternative?**

Note we don't have [children](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) or [childcare](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare) either, so perhaps one of those would be preferable. We do have [family](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family), but it isn't widely or consistently used.

Comment: No objections here

Comment: BTW I'm not too fond of the [family] tag. It seems appropriate on only 2 of the 4 tagged questions. We could make it a duplicate of [home] or simply remove it.

Comment: @THelper I like the idea of making it a synonym, so it doesn't blow up the front page (like I just did -- oops). Or would deleting the tag not trigger an edit on the associated questions?

Comment: All 'manual' tag edits push questions to the homepage, all bulk tag edits (merge tag or create synonym) do not. It's only 5 questions you modified so that's okay. I usually limit myself to 3-5 questions when doing manual tag changes.